# Using Redis and mysql with docker container

Tags: mysql, redis, docker

My web application needs both mysql and redis server to function properly. I am able to link mysql container with app using link tag (mysql is name of mysql image set using -name tag)

```
sudo docker run -link mysql:amq -d -p 13310 hitesh/image node app
```

Now I am not sure how to attach redis to this container. Should it be done via same mysql image (if yes, how two ports i.e. 3306 & 6379 will be exposed?) or should I make another container for redis and link it to my node.js app (not sure about it is possible or not).

Answer (score 0):

You should have 3 containers

1. your app
2. your mysql
3. your redis

then expose your mysql port and redis port on the relevant containers.

Then when you run your app container just link both mysql and redis containers to your app

so something like

```
sudo docker run -d -link mysql:mysql -link redis:redis ....
```

Now your app container will have environment variables for your other two databases

Also, if you want to expose two ports, then in your dockerfile just do EXPOSE port1 port2

e.g. EXPOSE 22 80

Then you'll get environment variables for both exposed ports. But i'd recommend you don't have a container that runs both mysql and redis. Separate your concerns :)

Comment: I tried this but my environment variables arent changed with respect to second -link parameter. Are you sure this will work?
Individually both mysql and redis are working fine.
Command used >>>
sudo docker run -link mysql:amq -link redis:amq -i -t -p 13310 hitesh/image /bin/bash

Comment: It should work, referencing: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/docker-user/Do0J26F-vS8/tEAvSeUdDY4J

Comment: no luck. its just ignoring the latter -link altogether.

Comment: What version of docker are you using?  sudo docker version

Comment: Client version: 0.8.0
Go version (client): go1.2
Git commit (client): cc3a8c8
Server version: 0.8.0
Git commit (server): cc3a8c8
Go version (server): go1.2

Comment: are you sure you expose ports on both containners? Try them both once at a time and see if you get the variables then. Then try them together as stated here. If you don't get all the variables then you might want to submit a bug to docker.